# Can vitae be synthesized into a pill?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-20th-anniversary

For my *Vampire: the Masquerade* game, I was thinking of one of the recruitment methods for the encroaching vampires to have their ghouls sell vitae condensed in the form of a pill while pretending to sell drugs.

Is it possible to give vitae the form of a pill and give it to someone in order to ghoul said person?

I am aware that I can just say it is possible as the Storyteller, but if possible, I would like to base it on a piece of lore. Please include which book the information is from in your answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Principal Focus of Vitae Infusion

It's a second-rank Thaumaturgical ritual that puts a blood point's worth of vitae into an object that can be "as small as a dime." (V20, p.234) A placebo or sugar pill could be that size — you might need to wash it down with something, but it's plausible. As the caster, you control when it turns back into your vitae, so once it's been swallowed, you trigger it.

Comment: And this is also a solid lore justification for a Tremere to invent blood pills that change back by themselves. It's a very small change to the ritual and the Tremere are experts on blood bonding after all.